# MS Access 2016 All subform buttons grayed out and font over-sized after upgrade

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Ever since I upgraded to Access 2016 my sub-form buttons get grayed out when moving from design or layout view to form view. During this time the buttons are active and usable but with the incorrect formatting. This gets corrected as soon as I close the form completely, but the issue always comes back. Yes, I have tried to compact/repair - this happens with new databases too. The other main oddity is that all text is over-sized in labels, buttons, etc. despite the font size being the same as before the upgrade from 2010. This problem only seems to appear on my PC (Windows 7 - 64 bit / Office 2016 - 64 bit as well). All other PCs at work do not see this behavior, not even my home PC. This creates a problem because as a developer of many Access apps at work (I'm no expert) this leaves me unable to do my work effectively. We have repaired and reinstalled Office, and my IT guy cleaned up the registry multiple times, yet no luck. Images here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6yAV.jpg

I'm new to Stackoverflow but I have accessed the site for quite a while. Thanks in advance. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think some screenshots would be helpful - of the form displayed wrong on your PC, and correct on other PCs. Please upload them to imgur.com, edit your post and add the links.

Comment: I just added a link to the screenshots under the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folks my apologies for the late update. There were some registry issues during the installation as the tech performing the work did some registry changes for unknown reasons. The issue was only resolved after removing all traces of Office and reinstalling it again. Note that a repair or a simple reinstall didn't work, you would need a complete overhaul; at least in my situation. This has been successfully resolved.